# Cakephp 2.x #hash not working in pagination number

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, pagination

i have problem to use **hash(#)** tag in cakephp pagination number.

***My Code:***

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(' <<' . __('Prev  '),array('url'=> array('#' => 'grid')),null,array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator'=>''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('  Next') . '>> ',array('url'=> array('#' => 'grid')),null,array('class' => 'next disabled'));
 ?>
```

I am getting hash(`#grid`) tag in both `<<Prev` and `Next>>` But i am unable to give `#grid` in between number.
Please help me how to use Hash link in pagination number?

Test link - http://vanceblackburn.com/Demo/carscanner/cars/listing/?make_id=&price1=&price2=&state_id=&title=

Comment: what do you mean by giving hash between numbers?

Comment: Please run my above code in your cakephp project you will know details what link is going your `<<Prev`, `Next>>` and the pagination numbers like 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: so you jest wanted to add # to numbers. just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(' <<' . __('Prev  '),array('url'=> array('#' => 'grid')),null,array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('url'=>array('#' => 'grid')),array('separator'=>''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('  Next') . '>> ',array('url'=> array('#' => 'grid')),null,array('class' => 'next disabled'));
 ?>
```